# analysis of two transistors ib,ic,ie?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog

is the ib current correct i went the KVL through the first transistor 
[image: Analysis]

Comment: Have you tried simulating this circuit and measuring the values?

Comment: A sim will give you much more accurate results than short-hand calcs.

Comment: You cannot compute Ib unless you state that Vc >>2.6V otherwise it draws more current.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 or more accurately, define that the transistors are not saturated.

Comment: @vofa I'm sure this is a school assignment where using SPICE software won't help you show your steps.

Comment: @KingDuken - Certainly, but Spice verifies that your hand calculations are valid, which is what OP is asking.

Comment: @vofa :) Agreed. Which is why there are meters in my answer... I use the simulator to check the sanity of the math I'm answering with.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 though now I see it.. in the picture it does state Ie is defined by the non-saturated equation.

Comment: @vofa Touche :) but also have to make sure OP is using the right formulas and knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are forgetting Re.

You also need to use the effective resistances for R4 and R6, which is their value

\$R4_e = R4 * (1+\beta) = 40,000 * 101 = 4,040,000\Omega\$
\$R6_e = R6 * (1+\beta) = 1,000 * 101 = 101,000\Omega\$

Using those your base circuit now looks like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCW2Gj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could solve that using various methods, but a shortcut is to realise that, for ideal Vbe, the voltage at the top of both emitter resistors is identical. As such you can treat both legs as being in parallel. The circuit can then be further simplified to..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frijAK.png)</sup>

Now you should be able to calculate the current through the circuit as..

\$I_{Rb} = (2.6 - 0.6)/(2,260 + 98,540) =  19.84uA\$

That makes the base voltages both..

\$V_b = 2.6 - 19.84uA * 2.26k\Omega = 2.555V\$

So

\$Ib1 = (2.555-0.6)/4.04M\Omega = 0.484uA\$.. and
\$Ib2 = (2.555-0.6)/101k\Omega = 19.356uA\$

**HOWEVER:** These numbers only make sense if the transistor is not saturated.  However the question also states \$I_e \approx \beta * I_B\$ which indicates in this case they are not.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a resistance in the right hand side of the equation.

\$2.6V = 2.26k\Omega\cdot I_{B1} + V_{BE} + 1k\Omega\cdot I_{E1}\$

Comment: it will give u Ie1 it is not big deal, Ie1 is approximatively equal to beta Ib ("100Ib")

Comment: It will give you an erroneous result unless you divide all quantities by \$10^3\$. Your result is off by 3 orders of magnitude.